# TFS 2015 xaml build TypeScript 2.x "experimentalDecorators" in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: angular, typescript, msbuild, tfsbuild

We have a tfs 2015 with "old" xaml Builds and I want to deploy a Angular 2 website with webpack.

I can install npm and compile my project with webpack on the tfs by adding simple Target that works fine I see my node_modules folder and the compiled wwwroot on the tfs temp dir.

```
 <PropertyGroup>
   <WebsitePath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)/../../Gui/Web/</WebsitePath>
   ...
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="npminstall">
 <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(WebsitePath)" Command="npm install" />
 <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(WebsitePath)" Command="npm run build:dev" />
</Target>
```

but the TFS Agent gives me a error message when it tries to compile the .net dlls

```
Build: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release.
Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
```

I know this error I got in the beginning with VS and NG2 I need to add some nodes in my csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DevMvc|AnyCPU'">
  <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
  <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
  <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
  <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
  <TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
  <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
  <TypeScriptOutFile />
  <TypeScriptOutDir />
  <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
  <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
  <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  <TypeScriptMapRoot />
  <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
  <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
  <TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>True</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
  <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and then the project in VS compiles, I've added this lines again to my csproj but its not helping/working for the TFS build

In VS I am currently using a tsconfig.json

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "types": [
      "node" 
    ]
  },
   "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
     "useWebpackText": true
   },
  "exclude": [
       "node_modules",
       "dist",
       "typings/main",
       "typings/index.d.ts"
     ],
     "compileOnSave": true
   }
```

someone got a idea what I have to do to get this project compilled on the TFS 2015.

TypeScript 2.0.6 is also installed on the Build Server.

Comment: Have you give a try with manually run your project in VS on the build agent/ server? Maybe it's an environment issue and what's the detail error when you run your project with xaml build on TFS2015 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we upgraded from tfs 2010 we don't change our xaml Processtemplate to the new one. All I had to do was to choose one of the new Xaml Buildprocesstemplates included in TFS 2015